# Access DLL without instantiating

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

I wrote a simple dll with only 2 functions in it.  Is there a way to access these functions without having to instantiate them on every page?

Can't I add them to the web.config somehow as assemblies thus giving me access to them?

Comment: Welcome to the world of object orientation.

Answer (score 1):

Mark your methods as `static` and you can call them from anywhere without instantiating the classes.

Your class:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public static string HelloWorld()
  {
    return "Hello World";
  }
}
```

Your Page:

```
string helloWord = MyClass.HelloWorld();
```

[Static Classes and Static Class Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(VS.80).aspx) explained.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the functions on each page, put them into a base class of all of your pages.